# Retrieving text from html is not working with python

Tags: python, html

I am trying to scrape company contact info, I have been able to get the everthing else except the phone number. This is the html

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Harrrrrell   INC</h3>
    </li>
    <li>43 Airpark Ct</li>
    <li>Alabaster, MD 35107</li>
    <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Phone</span>: 888-232-8358</li>
    <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">Corporate URL</span>: <a href="http://www.hhsales.com" rel="nofollow" target="new">www.h23hsales.com</a></li>
    <li><span style="font-weight: bold;">More Detail</span>:<br> <a href="https://www.collierreporting.com/company/harrell-and-hall-enterprises-inc-alabaster-al">Click for Full Harrell &amp; Hall Enterprises INC Dossier</a></li>
</ul>
```

This python script works for everything else in this html except the phone number.

```
for companyLIST in result[0:]:
            try:

                companyname = companyLIST.find('h3').contents[0]
                print("Company Name ",str(companyname) )
            except Exception as e:
                print("errror",str(e))

            try:
                companySt = companyLIST.find_all('li')[1].contents[0]
                print("Company St ",str(companySt) )
            except Exception as e:
                print("errror",str(e))

            try:
                companyCity = companyLIST.find_all('li')[2].contents[0]
                print("Company City ",str(companyCity) )
            except Exception as e:
                print("errror",str(e))

            try:
                companyPhone= companyLIST.find('li')[3].contents[0]
                print("Company Phone ",companyPhone )

            except Exception as e:
                print("errror",str(e))

            try:
                companyWeb = companyLIST.find('a')['href'] 

                print("Company Web ",str(companyWeb) )
                print("  " )

            except Exception as e:
                print("errror",str(e))
```

this is a sample output for

Company Name  Harrrrrell   INC

Company St  43 Airpark Ct

Company City  Alabaster, MD 35107

errror 3

Company Web  https://www.collierreporting.com/company/harrell-and-hall-enterprises-inc-alabaster-al

> **Traceback (most recent call last):**
>
> ```
>   File "sample.py", line 26, in <module>
>     companyPhone = soup.find('li')[3].contents[0]
>   File "...dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1011, in __getitem__
>     return self.attrs[key]
> KeyError: 3
> ```

how could rewrite the code below to get the phone number?

```
companyPhone= companyLIST.find('li')[3].contents[0]
                print("Company Phone ",companyPhone )
```

Comment: what do you get as result?

Comment: Does your find function returns list of `li`? Also could you provide error message?

Comment: Remove your `try ... except` to get the Traceback output. Reread the [BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find). `find()` just returns the result not a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using beatifulsoup4 library for parsing HTML. If yes, you can get phone number from html like this:

```
text = soup.find_all('li')[3].contents[1]
phone_number = re.sub(": ", "", text)

print(phone_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
companyPhone= companyLIST.find('li')[3].contents[0]
            print("Company Phone ",companyPhone )
```

with

```
if "Phone" in companyLIST:                                                                                                 
    companyPhone = companyLIST.split(':')[-1].replace(' ','').replace('</li>','')
```

Code above splits list by ':' character, selects last element, and deletes useless information. In the end we have only the phone number as a separate string. You can do the same with rest of lines just select splitting character/string wisely and clean up resulting list element with replace function.

Hope it is useful.